# PyMC3 passing stochastic covariance matrix to pm.MvNormal()

Tags: python, theano, bayesian, normal-distribution, pymc3

I've tried to fit a simple 2D gaussian model to observed data by using PyMC3.

```
import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pm

n = 10000;
np.random.seed(0)
X = np.random.multivariate_normal([0,0], [[1,0],[0,1]], n);

with pm.Model() as model:
    # PRIORS
    mu = [pm.Uniform('mux', lower=-1, upper=1), 
          pm.Uniform('muy', lower=-1, upper=1)]
    cov = np.array([[pm.Uniform('a11', lower=0.1, upper=2), 0],
                    [0, pm.Uniform('a22', lower=0.1, upper=2)]])

    # LIKELIHOOD
    likelihood = pm.MvNormal('likelihood', mu=mu, cov=cov, observed=X)

with model:
    trace = pm.sample(draws=1000, chains=2, tune=1000)
```

while I can do this in 1D by passing the `sd` to `pm.Normal`, I have some trouble in passing the covariance matrix to `pm.MvNormal`.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

**PyMC3 distribution objects are not simple numeric objects or numpy arrays**. Instead, they are nodes in a theano computation graph and often require operations from either [`pymc3.math`](https://docs.pymc.io/api/math.html) or [`theano.tensor`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html) to manipulate them. Moreover, placing PyMC3 objects in numpy arrays is unnecessary since they already are multidimensional.

### Original Model

Keeping with the intent of your code, a working version would go something like

```
import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pm
import theano.tensor as tt

N = 10000
np.random.seed(0)
X = np.random.multivariate_normal(np.zeros(2), np.eye(2), size=N)

with pm.Model() as model:
    # use `shape` argument to define tensor dimensions
    mu = pm.Uniform('mu', lower=-1, upper=1, shape=2)

    # diagonal values on covariance matrix
    a = pm.Uniform('a', lower=0.1, upper=2, shape=2)

    # convert vector to a 2x2 matrix with `a` on the diagonal
    cov = tt.diag(a)

    likelihood = pm.MvNormal('likelihood', mu=mu, cov=cov, observed=X)
```

### Alternative Model

I assume the example you provided is just a toy to communicate the problem. But just in case, I'll mention that the main advantage of using a multivariate normal (modeling covariance between parameters) is lost when restricting the covariance matrix to be diagonal. Furthermore, the theory of priors for covariance matrices is well-developed, so it's worth one's time considering existing solutions. In particular, there is [a PyMC3 example using the LKJ prior for covariance matrices](https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/LKJ.html).

Here's a simple application of that example in this context:

```
with pm.Model() as model_lkj:
    # use `shape` argument to define tensor dimensions
    mu = pm.Uniform('mu', lower=-1, upper=1, shape=2)

    # LKJ prior for covariance matrix (see example)
    packed_L = pm.LKJCholeskyCov('packed_L', n=2,
                                 eta=2., sd_dist=pm.HalfCauchy.dist(2.5))
    # convert to (2,2)
    L = pm.expand_packed_triangular(2, packed_L)

    likelihood = pm.MvNormal('likelihood', mu=mu, chol=L, observed=X)
```

Comment: merv, thanks for the answer. Mine example was a toy model and I could use other ways as you suggested. In general I have difficulties in understanding how to include in the model custom operators. I have a topic similar on https://discourse.pymc.io/t/multivariate-gaussian-with-custom-operator-mean/2212 where I have problem in including a "physical law" for the stochastic mean.